# JSP Beancommunication

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to create a JSP side for my assessment.
At present I'm a little stuck over some simple problems:

I have a LoginBean, and a ActionBean.

For one Method of the ActionBean I need the Username, that is stored in the LoginBean.

I already set the Loginbean to session scope.

Problem:

How to get the Username variable from the LoginBean Object at the ActionBean?

What i tried:

```
FacesContext context= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getAttributes().put("Username",Usernamevariable);
```

in the Bean which is used by the Loginpage to check if the user can login
and

```
Username=context.getAttributes().get("Username").toString();
```

in the Bean that wants to performe the Action for which the Username is needed.

On second thought that did not work, because it are to different pages so the context is different.

What would a working solution?

Comment: will you extremely please post small code where you stuck?

Comment: Please post some code as we are unable to imagine your senerio and let us know what you have tried so far.

Comment: I by luck, i already found an answer, using FacesContexts.getAttributes()

Comment: EDIT: command revert, the solution I thought didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in ActionBean should do the job

```
    LoginBean loginBean= (LoginBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getApplication()
        .evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{LoginBean}", LoginBean.class);
    // after that you can do sth like this
    String username = loginBean.getUsername();
```